# Unable to clone bitbucket repository

Tags: git, ubuntu, bitbucket

I'm following this tutorial: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creating-a-professional-wordpress-development-workflow-with-vagrant--cms-21121

I am unable to proceed past this step:

$git clone [my-cloned repository] /desired-path-to-project/
$cd /desired-path-to-project/

I've never used bitbucket before and this is a brand new Ubuntu installation so I believe I might be missing a step setting up git on it. Any pointers are appreciated! I've never set up SSH to connect to bitbucket so that may be where I need help.

Thanks!

Comment: have you added your ssh key or know what that is?

Comment: What "protocol" are you using, i.e. git clone http | ssh | git @...

Comment: No, the tutorial didn't mention that but I believe that is where I need help since I did that on my Macbook when setting up the ability to push to GitHub from terminal.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: macbooks are super easy to use with ssh. I HIGHLY suggest that you look into ssh, however if you are more interested in just getting ssh working then use https

Comment: your connection url should be something like git clone https:// USERNAME@bitbucket.org:PASSWORD/USERNAME/REPO_NAME.git

Comment: Here is the error I am getting now after following their tutorial:

Warning: Permanently added 'bitbucket.org,131.103.20.168' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

Answer (score 0):

The tutorial Atlasian (company that makes bitbucket) provides for ssh is pretty good, I'd suggest you follow their steps. 
https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Set+up+SSH+for+Git

Answer (score 0):

SSH is an excellent tool that you should look into for primary git usage. However to access your repo quickly use the following url connection,

```
git clone https://USER_NAME@bitbucket.org:PASSWORD/USER_NAME/REPO_NAME.git
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked for now but I would still like to learn how to get the SSH to work - public key was getting error that I posted above.

Comment: @MCHLWRRN did you run ssh-keygen -t rsa  to generate key? and then after that you need to copy your ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub to bitbucket, those are the two primary steps to ssh usage. After that you can use ssh as the 'protocol' with git.

Comment: in bitbucket you have to go to account(top right of screen)->add sshkeys to add your key.